# Rounding up even if Python is also less than 0.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, return-value, val

How to Rounding up even if Python is also less than 0.5?

- I use `round()` but if value is 3.12 less than 3.5 rounded value is 3 but I do want returned value is 4.
- process it may vary depend on the enter value.

I do want:

- 4.2 round to = 5
- 1.33 round to = 2
- 0.49 round to = 1
- 8.89 round to = 9

Comment: round() always rounds down, so you will have to make your own function

Comment: You can use `math.ceil` for this